existence and uniqueness of splitting fields
Let $F$ be a field and $f(x)\in F[x]$ be a monic polynomial. Denote by $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ the roots of $f(x)$ over $\bar F$ the algebraic closure of $F$. Then $f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n(x-a_i)$ splits completely in $\bar F[x]$.
[1] Can we directly say that $F(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ is the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $F$? This is because $F(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ and $\mathrm{spl}_Ff(x)$ are both defined to be the intersection of all subfields of $\bar F$ containing $F,a_1,\ldots,a_n$. I see that the proof of the existence of splitting fields uses induction on the degree of $f(x)$, but why don't we directly give the construction as above?
[2] Does $F(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ is the uniqueness splitting field containing $F$? It is said that splitting fields are unique up to isomorphisms, but are there any $K,K'$ that are both the splitting fields of $f(x)$ with $K\neq K'$? I can not give a counterexample if $F=\mathbb{Q}$.

This is a duplicate question. It's a basic characterization of splitting fields. Hence, experienced users should use site search and link a good duplicate, not post answers that were already given on this site multiple times. See here.

I normally hesitate to use my dupehammer privilege when I happen to have answered the target question. In this case I assume that Martin approves, so I will. After all, a dupe closure is also reversible.

Having said that, I'm a bit surprised that I could not find nice threads on this theme prior to 2013.


Yes. Using the algebraic closure here is potentially circular, since one proof that the algebraic closure exists requires repeatedly constructing splitting fields (this is not the only possible proof). In any case constructing the algebraic closure is more difficult than constructing splitting fields, and e.g. requires more use of the axiom of choice. (Without AC, algebraic closures may not exist and they may not be unique, but splitting fields continue to exist and be unique up to isomorphism.)

There can be "different" but isomorphic splitting fields. To give an example of what kind of stuff can happen here, consider the polynomial $f(x) = x^2 + 1$. Over $\mathbb{Q}$, it has a splitting field inside $\mathbb{C}$, namely $\mathbb{Q}[i]$. But it also has a splitting field inside $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for any prime $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, namely $\mathbb{Q}[i_p]$ where $i_p \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ is one of the two $p$-adic integers satisfying $i_p^2 = -1$. These splitting fields are all isomorphic. But they are not "literally equal." (One way to argue this is that it is not possible to pick a canonical isomorphism between $\mathbb{Q}[i]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[i_p]$; you have to pick one of the two possible choices of $i_p$.)


